# How to know the utilization of intel CPU and GPU in Linux?

Tags: centos, command-line, terminal, intel-graphics

In ubuntu, to know the time taken by CPU to run a program we would use `time` in terminal. Whereas in case of intel GPU, we would use `intel_gpu_time`. But in case of CentOS `time` command works. But `intel_gpu_time` is not working. It is showing "command not found". How to know the utilization and time of intel CPU and GPU in CentOS?

Comment: You install the package that provides `intel_gpu_time` that is, `intel-gpu-tools` ?

Answer (score 5):

Never known about the command `intel_gpu_time` interesting, thank you. This command is part of the package `intel-gpu-tools` (apt-get install intel-gpu-tools) under Ubuntu and by the look of it the package under RedHat (CentOS) is called exactly the same.

So, give `yum install intel-gpu-tools` a try.